# Way to have Accelerate Mouse Pointer?

Tags: 11.10, mouse, touchpad

Id like to know if there is anything to do to have accelerated motion of mouse pointer in 11.10, i.e. A small jerk of mouse or touchpad would push the pointer to more-than-usual distance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is.

Go to System Settings and select "Mouse and touchpad". There a two tabs, one for an external mouse and another for the touchpad.

Here you'll find a slider for acceleration and sensitivity. Changes in the settings should be immediate, so you can test it right away.

---

Some other programs like `gpointing-device-settings` let you set separate minimum and maximum speeds, for a bit more control.

If you're looking for a "deceleration" effect, where the mouse keeps moving after letting go of the touchpad, I haven't found a way to achieve this.